# MVC || HTML Form || Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, http-post, forms

I get this error and i dont know how to over come it:

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
Line 48:         public ActionResult Upload(imageFile imageFile)
Line 49:         {
Line 50:             foreach (var image in imageFile.files)
Line 51:             {
Line 52:                 if (image.ContentLength > 0)
```

I tried using ID attribute and name attribute and what not...

This is the problematic section in my controller :

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(imageFile imageFile)
    {
        foreach (var image in imageFile.files)
        {
            if (image.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = _blobStorageService.GetCloudBlobContainer();
                CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(image.FileName);
                blob.UploadFromStream(image.InputStream);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Upload");
    }
```

This is the HTML.Form :

```
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="file" name="imageFile" id="imageFile" multiple />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
    }
</p>
```

And this is the "imageFile" class :

```
public class imageFile
{
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files { get; set; }
}
```

What i'm doing wrong ? i read a lot of posts about this exception but none of them helped me..

Thank you.

Comment: The exceptions means you are trying to use an object (imageFile) but it is null.  This is probably the most common exception

Comment: Try changing the name of the parameter in your actions from imageFile to file. Sometimes the bindings are finicky.

Comment: @KyleGobel yeah i got it, you have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: @Josh there isn't more conventional solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the name of your html input to be **files**, as in your model class:

Your input element in the view:

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple />
```

Your model:

```
public class imageFile
{
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files { get; set; }
}
```